# Drag and Drop to MS Paint doesn't work on Windows 8, C#, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop images from my app to others like Word, Outlook, Power Point... 
The code that I have now works fine on these apps, but when I try to drop an image to MS Paint it doesn't work. Sometimes I receive a message with path not found showing a path to C:\system32 folder.

PS: If I try to drop an image from Windows Explorer it works, but if I try to drop from Firefox for exemple the same error occurs. 
This code works fine on Windows 7, but not on Windows 8.

```
private void clipboardListView_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     switch (item.Type)
     {
        case DashboardItem.ContentType.IMG:

        string[] fileName = new string[] { item.ImagePath };
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, fileName), DragDropEffects.Copy);
     }
}
```

Comment: I think those applications don't use File as their DataFormat. try other DataFormats. maybe clipboard?

Comment: I tried other DataForts unsuccessfully, but DataFormats.FileDrop shoud work because is the same format that comes from Windows Explorer.